# ffmpeg: Remove an exact hex color?

Tags: ffmpeg, gif, video-processing, animated-gif

i'm editing .gifs and it is a MUST that we remove a specific hex encoding from the gif and place the background behind it.

This is all working fine, the problem is that 'colorkey' arg at its lowest default value (0.01) removes 'similar colors' to your input, not the exact value. So it's screwing up the entire gif by removing colors we don't need removed!

Also tried chromakey, which does claim to be exact in the docs. Just doesn't work for gifs apparently, we're getting black pixels everywhere.

This should be an easy problem, so how do we remove an exact hex color on a .gif? Code below, although it doubt it helps. Thanks.

```
-i background.png -i gifInfo.gif -i foreground.png -filter_complex '[0:v]split [a][b];[a] palettegen=stats_mode=full[p];[b][p] paletteuse=new=1[pbgout];[pbgout]scale=w=350:h=-1,pad=1080:1080:x=350:y=470[bgout];[1:v]colorkey=0x080806:[ckout];[bgout][ckout]overlay[olout];[olout][2:v]overlay[oloutb];[oloutb]split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen=stats_mode=full[p];[s1][p]paletteuse=dither=none' -y testingGif.gif
```